# Encryption/decryption program

Tags: c++

Here is a little encryptor I wrote, I'm just asking for people to tell me what is good practice and what's not. Also, I mean the code, not the actual encryption (because it's just a dumb thing).

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int encrypter(int input);
int decrypter(int input);
bool whatToDoFunc();

int main()
{
    try
    {
        bool keepGoing = true;

        while (keepGoing)
        {
            bool success = whatToDoFunc(); char redo;
            cout << "Press 'y' to redo or anykey to exit" << endl;
            cin >> redo;
            if (success == true && (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y'))
                keepGoing == true;
            else
                keepGoing = false;
        }
        }
    catch (runtime_error err)
    {
        cout << err.what() << endl;
        char exitCon;
        cout << "Enter anykey to exit" << endl;
        cin >> exitCon;
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}

bool whatToDoFunc()
{
    int input;
    char whatToDo;
    cout << "Welcome to the JeGo encrypter what do you want to do encrypt or     decrypy? Enter E or D\n" << endl;
    cin >> whatToDo;
    if (whatToDo == 'e' || whatToDo == 'E')
    {
        cout << "Enter the number you want to encrypt" << endl;
        cin >> input;
        int inputEncrypted = encrypter(input);
        cout << "Your number encrypted is " << inputEncrypted << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        if (whatToDo == 'd' || whatToDo == 'D')
        {
            cout << "Enter the already encrypted number" << endl;
            cin >> input;
            int numDecrypted = decrypter(input);
            cout << "Your number decrypted is " << numDecrypted << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            cerr << "Error" << endl;
            throw runtime_error("Your input was invalid");
        }
    }

return true;
}

int encrypter(int input)
{
    int inputEncrypted;
    inputEncrypted = ((((input * 2) + 7) + 5) + 8);
    if (inputEncrypted % 2 == 0)
        ++inputEncrypted;
    else
        inputEncrypted = inputEncrypted + (13 + 13) + (11 + 11);
    return inputEncrypted;
}

int decrypter(int inputEncrypted)
{
    int decryptedNum = 0;
    if (inputEncrypted % 2 == 1)
        --inputEncrypted;
    else
    {
        (11 - 11) - (13 - 13) - inputEncrypted;
    }
    decryptedNum = ((((inputEncrypted - 8) - 5) - 7) / 2);
    return decryptedNum;
}
```

Please tell me what I could do to make it better or just nicer design! :)

Comment: Note: the line `(11 - 11) - (13 - 13) - inputEncrypted;` does *absolutely nothing*.

Comment: @immibis not right. That instruction can bring `inputEncrypted` to a negative number.

Comment: @Pr0kram3r Except that it is not saved...

Comment: That's not what @OP was intended to do.

Answer (score 15):

#### Bug?

It looks like there is a bug here:

> ```
> else
> {
>     (11 - 11) - (13 - 13) - inputEncrypted;
> }
> ```

After simplification, the expression becomes:

```
else
{
    -inputEncrypted;
}
```

... which does nothing, as the result is not assigned, the value of `inputEncrypted` is unchanged. If you wanted to negate the value of the variable, you would have to write like this:

```
else
{
    inputEncrypted = -inputEncrypted;
}
```

I don't know if this is your real intention (didn't look at your code close enough). But the original code does absolutely nothing, it's reduced to a statement whose result is not stored anywhere.

#### Use boolean expressions directly

This can be simplified:

> ```
> if (success == true && (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y'))
>     keepGoing == true;
> else
>     keepGoing = false;
> ```

To this:

```
keepGoing = success && (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y');
```

Notice how you don't need to write `x == true`, you can use boolean expressions directly.

#### Naming

A name like `whatToDoFunc` is obviously bad. Good function names are extremely important to understand how a program works.

Answer (score 14):

**`encrypter`**

```
int encrypter(int input)
{
    return (input * 2) + 21;
}
```

Works the same as your function. To get to that I did the following:

- Folding compile time expression.
- Using ternaries.
- Noting that `x * 2 + 20` is always even.
- Returning directly with no intermediate variable.

**`decrypter`**

`decrypter` is just the inverse of `encrypter` so:

```
int decrypter(int input)
{
    return (input - 21) / 2;
}
```

Comment: Ok I changed it

Comment: I frequently see parenthesis being used unnecessarily, like you did here `return (input * 2) + 21;`. Is it supposed to be like this to avoid confusion or you made it this way because you/the OP/someone may not know that `*` gets evaluated before `+`? This kind of rule seems pretty straightforward and I think it works the same for every language.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho In simple expressions it is the same to use or not parenthesis.

Comment: @TiagoMarinho, yeah I think this same thing. But some people really like not having to memorize the order of operations, e.g. `a || b && c`. Personally I think they should get over it or find a different language that fits their preferences (Lisp).

Answer (score 6):

## Naming

`whatToDoFunc` and `whatToDo` are bad names. Use appropriate naming.

## Implementation

- Using `using namespace std;` is bad for ambiguity.
- Don't use `std::endl`, use `'\n'`.
- You can simplify some newbie expressions.

You have:

```
 if (success == true && (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y'))
                keepGoing == true;
            else
                keepGoing = false;
        }
```

which can be simplified to:

```
keepGoing = success && (redo == 'y' || redo == 'Y');
```

---

The `encrypter` function can be simplified to:

```
int encrypter(int input)
{
    return (input * 2) + 21;
}
```

---

The `decrypter` function can be simplified to:

```
int decrypter(int inputEncrypted)
{
    int firstresult = inputEncrypted % 2 == 1 ? --inputEncrypted : ((11 - 11) - (13 - 13) - inputEncrypted);
    return ((firstresult - 20) / 2);
}
```

by using ternaries. Yes, you can do it in one line, but it's preferred to make it more readable.

---

- `getchar()` is useful in some cases.

  You have:

  ```
  cout << "Enter anykey to exit" << endl;
      cin >> exitCon;
  ```

  This is not right. Actually, the user needs to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, not any key. So, replace the `cin >> exitCon;` with `getchar();` (avoid `system()` functions).

Maybe there is a bug in your program in the `encrypt`/`decrypt` functions.

Answer (score 4):

- Signed integer overflow is undefined behavior. Use `unsigned int` and let it wrap around instead. Otherwise you risk a compiler "optimizing" your code by removing it by proving that it would cause an integer overflow.
- The operation `* 2` is not reversible, because you may lose information. The highest bit that you are shifting away should be put to the first bit, making it a bit rotation operation.

  Example: If you were using `unsigned char` then `200 * 2 = 400 % 256 = 144` and `72 * 2 = 144` and if you want to decrypt a `144` you don't know if it should be `200` or `72`. Same applies to integers, just with bigger numbers.

  The solution is to use bit rotation instead which is a bit awkward, but you can check it out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776508).

Answer (score 0):

The usual recommendations apply:

- Test your code before posting it here. In particular, make sure that for every possible integer, encrypting it and decrypting it results in the same number.
- Enable all available compiler warnings and try to understand them. They prevent you from wasting other people's time. If there are warnings that you cannot understand, ask about them.